# PHP YouTube Live Streaming API insufficientPermissions Error

Tags: php, youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to access the listLiveBroadcasts through "YouTube Live Streaming API" (YouTube Data API v3). I have Auth 2.0 access and successfully get the token every time. With same logic I am accessing the Google+ Calendar events successfully, I have enabled the YouTube API also. but when I am trying to list :

```
$youtube->liveBroadcasts->listLiveBroadcasts( 'id,contentDetails', array( 'mine' => 'true', ));
```

It gives error :

```
[domain] => global
[reason] => insufficientPermissions
[message] => Insufficient Permission
```

I have tried everything, Set the scope to $scopes to

```
auth/youtube;
```

tried also by including :

```
force-ssl
readonly
```

Same code is working at

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list
```

with google's example api key.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using Google's sample API key. Create a new application in the Developer Console and use that application's API key.